# Proving that ${\textrm{gcd}} (n, p-1) = 1$ if $p$ is the prime is the smallest prime divisor of $ n $

Tags: number-theory

Show that if $n>1$ is a positive integer and $p$ is the prime is the smallest prime divisor of $ n $ then $ {\textrm{mcd}} (n, p-1) = 1$.

Comment: Is $\operatorname{mcd}$ the Spanish name of the greatest common divisor ($\gcd$)?

Comment: yes, it means máximo común divisor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose to the contrary that $\gcd(n,p-1)=d\gt 1$.

Then some prime $q$ divides $d$. It follows that $q$ divides $n$, and $q\lt p$, contradicting the fact that $p$ is the *smallest* prime divisor of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $\operatorname{mcd}(n,p-1)=d>1$. Then $d\mid n$, but since $d\leq p-1<p$, we have a contradiction, since $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of $n$. So $\operatorname{mcd}(n,p-1)=1$.